# When I put my computer to sleep I can't turn it back on without me manually shutting it down and turning it back on

Tags: power

It is a Lenovo G510s Touch, and it is a very annoying issue. I tried going into the control panel and changing what the power button does, but that has not worked. I have no idea what the problem is. It is a fairly new laptop, and has worked well up until now.

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning what operating system you're running (Windows 7 32/64 bit, Windows 8, some variant of Linux). Your mention of the control panel makes me suspect Windows, but it's rather difficult to know which version.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop > choose Personalization > Click on Screen Saver > Change Power Settings > Change when the computer sleeps > Change advanced power settings.

From here you can change different sleep options, What your PC is probably set to do is hibernate after you hit the power button and not sleep.  Check the options under > Sleep button action, they are probably set to hibernate not sleep.

PS from the documentation wheich can be found here: http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g410stouchg510stouch_ug_english.pdf
Your PC "When in sleep mode, you can only use keyboard instead of mouse to wake up the 
computer"